# Ir a um determinado link conforme Radio Box com PHP

Tags: php, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o código a seguir. Como posso determinar uma URL, passando parametro, conforme a opção em um Radio Box selecionado?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Outra Forma de Pagamento
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Escolha a Forma de Pagamento</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            Cartão de Crédito e/ou Débito
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
            Boleto Bancário
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
            Débito em Conta
        </label>
  </div>
```

**Código completo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Escolha forma de Pagamento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Doar
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Escolha a Forma de Pagamento</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                Cartão de Crédito e/ou Débito
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                Boleto Bancário
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                Débito em Conta
            </label>
      </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução**

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="getRadio">Continuar</button>
```

JS

```
  $().ready(function () {

    $("#getRadio").click(function () {
      if ($("input[name=exampleRadios]:checked").val() == "option1") {
        // ação aqui
      }
      else if (outra condição) {
        // ação aqui
      }
      else if (outra condição) {
        // ação aqui
      }
    })

  })
```

**Explicação**

Adicione um `id` no botão `continuar`, já que pelo que vi da lógica, você só irá precisar do valor do campo `radio` quando a pessoa clicar em `continuar`. Então com `JQuery`, você adiciona um evento `click`, e no evento você irá pegar o valor do campo `radio` que está `checked` e comparar com as opções de valores e adicionar a ação que deseja realizar.

Comment: funcionou perfeito. Muito obrigado. \ö/